# how to set the edittext value of another fragment when user swipe the page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I used tab,pageviewer and fragment. I want to change my edittext value when user swipe the page ....
For example I have two tabs in first tab user input two integer value and on page swipe/change tab i want to set the addition of that two inputs on edittext view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fragments in a activity should not communicate directly with each other. The modular way would be to, send the 2 EditText values to the Activity. Add the 2 values in the activity and send the value to the next fragment.

Update: Set the text at onActivityCreated of the Fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        editText.setText(text);
    }
```

if that is not working also, try with a Handler(), like this,

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.setText(text);
            }
        });

        }
```

Comment: i  can pass value on the second fragment but onCreateView i can't set that value on edittext view

Comment: Do not set the text at onCreateView. Try setting the text at onActivityCreated()

Comment: if its not working at onActivityCreated() also, try with a Handler.post()

Comment: How to use onActivityCreated() and Handler.post() use in Fragment

Comment: But still i have a one problem. When i set value on second fragment i need to go on first fragment and then i'll set the value on edittext of third fragment.

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: i have 3 pages ... In first page i have some value ...... in second page i set some value which should be get on third page But My problem is when i go to second page to third page value is not set in edittext but i have to go to first page and then go to third page then the value is set on edittext...

Comment: Are you using ViewPager to have 3 pages?

Comment: ViewPager will create and have the previous and next page in memory. When you are in the second page itself, ViewPager will create the Next Page(third page) in its memory. So that swiping to the next page will be seamless. When you go to first page, it will destroy the third page. Upon coming back to the second page, it will again create the third page.

Comment: I want to know, how are you sending the data from second page to third page?

Comment: i fetch data from previous page using static method of the previous page. Example FirstFragment class have method getNumber(), In second Fragment call the method like this FirstFragment.getNumber();..

Comment: how are you sending the data from second page to third page?

Comment: i fetch data from previous page using static method of the previous page. Example FirstFragment class have method getNumber(), In second Fragment call the method like this FirstFragment.getNumber();..

Comment: instead of getNumber(), you should try with setNumber(). When you have the data at the SecondFragment, call ThirdFragment.setNumber()

Comment: Still same problem ...... you know how to set the another fragment edittext from anotherfragment.....

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: You should keep track of all the fragments in the ViewPager adapter. Then when you want to set the data to another Fragment, get the reference of the Fragment from the adapter, and call a method to set the data. refer here for keeping references of fragments. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/4586742

Comment: So, instead of static methods, you should have a method setNumber() in Fragment3. From Fragment2, get the reference of Fragment3 from the Adapter, and call the method setNumber()

Comment: Example In first page i set some value and then go to second page. In Second page button click i want to go back first page and i want to see the previous value (In fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class and define a variable there, or define a variable in the parent activity, or use shared preferences, or use application context.

Comment: I can pass value on the second fragment but onCreateView i can't set that value on edittext view.